Re-enable secure boot on Kubuntu
I've recently tried to put my SSD into another computer because I had troubling with it. Anyway, I've put it back in the old one, the one I use actually.
When I did that, my OS wouldn't boot and I had a message that made me think that the secure boot was the problem, which was so I deleted all the keys in my BIOS thinking that Kubuntu would just put himself back in it.
It didn't, now my system boot without Secure Boot I'd like to enroll my MOK in my BIOS again. I've tried to manually do it by enrolling a PK but I don't know how to do it. Should I use a .efi files to enroll (mmx64, grubx64 or shimx64).
Thanks for the help.

If everything works without secure boot, then let it be as it is. Realistically you would not gain any extra security by turning on secure boot.

I normally so not use Secure Boot, but laptop uses external install from SSD. I installed from Desktop which is not Secure Boot. External SSD then would not boot on laptop. Ran this and then it seemed to work sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64-signed But I am not sure it installed signed kernels or not and later may have added them?

If you install the system with secure boot enabled, the system will boot correctly if secure boot is enabled or disabled...   However if you installed the system with secure boot disabled, the installer may not have installed the system so it can be booted on an secure boot system when enabled...  You've devoid of specifics though; was it installed with secure boot enabled most importantly?  and what was actually installed? as you don't mention anything but Kubuntu (no release details) thus we don't know which installer was used (Kubuntu has used ubiquity and calamares)

My bad, I forgot to put some details. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS - KDE Plasma : 5.24.7 - KDE Developping environment : 5.92.0 - Qt version : 5.13.3. Yes, I installed Kubuntu when Secure Boot was enable so it was always was on secure boot.
I deleted the secure boot keys from my OS on the BIOS and I'd like to put them back.
